# Ruby: Converting a nested Ruby hash to an un-nested one

Tags: ruby, hash, nested-attributes

Right now, I have a server call kicking back the following Ruby hash:

```
{
  "id"=>"-ct",
  "factualId"=>"",
  "outOfBusiness"=>false,
  "publishedAt"=>"2012-03-09 11:02:01",
  "general"=>{
    "name"=>"A Cote",
    "timeZone"=>"EST",
    "desc"=>"Ã€ CÃ´tÃ© is a small-plates restaurant in Oakland's charming
            Rockridge district. Cozy tables surround large communal tables in both
            the main dining room and on the sunny patio to create a festive atmosphere.
              Small plates reflecting the best of seasonal Mediterranean cuisine are served
            family-style by a friendly and knowledgeable staff.\nMenu items are paired with
            a carefully chosen selection of over 40 wines by the glass as well as a highly
            diverse bottled wine menu. Specialty drinks featuring fresh fruits, rare
            botaniques and fine liqueurs are featured at the bar.",
    "website"=>"http://acoterestaurant.com/"
  },
  "location"=>{
    "address1"=>"5478 College Ave",
    "address2"=>"",
    "city"=>"Oakland",
    "region"=>"CA",
    "country"=>"US",
    "postcode"=>"94618",
    "longitude"=>37.84235,
    "latitude"=>-122.25222
  },
  "phones"=>{
    "main"=>"510-655-6469",
    "fax"=>nil
  },
  "hours"=>{
    "mon"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "tue"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "wed"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "thu"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "fri"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "sat"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "sun"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""},
    "holidaySchedule"=>""
  },
  "businessType"=>"Restaurant"
}
```

It's got several attributes which are nested, such as:

```
"wed"=>{"start"=>"", "end"=>""}
```

I need to convert this object into a unnested hash in Ruby. Ideally, I'd like to detect if an attribute is nested, and respond accordingly, I.E. when it determines the attribute '`wed`' is nested, it pulls out its data and stores in the fields '`wed-start`' and '`wed-end`', or something similar.

Anyone have any tips on how to get started?

Comment: A little confused about your use of 'JSON' here.  What you are showing is a ruby hash, not a JSON object.  Do you need to flatten that hash, then convert back to JSON? Or, do you simply need to take that ruby hash and flatten it?

Comment: Yeah, turns out it actually was a ruby object. How do I flatten it?

Comment: There is a hash method called, flatten, but I don't think that's what your looking for.  It flattens a hash into an array.  I'm curious what your use case is.  It generally makes more sense to keep nesting, imho.  Its much easier to dynamically retrieve values like this `hash[var][var2]` than it is to try and concatenate keys on the fly, like `hash[var + "-" +var2]`  It's way less readable and doesn't really gain much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a first cut at a complete solution. I'm sure you can write it more elegantly, but this seems fairly clear. If you save this in a Ruby file and run it, you'll get the output I show below.

```
class Hash
  def unnest
    new_hash = {}
    each do |key,val|
      if val.is_a?(Hash)
        new_hash.merge!(val.prefix_keys("#{key}-"))
      else
        new_hash[key] = val
      end
    end
    new_hash
  end

  def prefix_keys(prefix)
    Hash[map{|key,val| [prefix + key, val]}].unnest
  end
end

p ({"a" => 2, "f" => 5}).unnest
p ({"a" => {"b" => 3}, "f" => 5}).unnest
p ({"a" => {"b" => {"c" => 4}, "f" => 5}}).unnest
```

Output:

```
{"a"=>2, "f"=>5}
{"a-b"=>3, "f"=>5}
{"a-b-c"=>4, "a-f"=>5}
```

Comment: I am probably wrong, but this feels like an anti-pattern to me.  It feels more icky trying to get at p[a-b-c] than it does p[a][b][c].  And it gets messy when you get more values in your hash.

Comment: yep. I am not explicitly commenting on the appropriateness of a solution like this, just supplying code for if people want it :)

Comment: @Joeyjoejoejr one example where this might be used is if you are stuffing a nested hash into an api or datastore that can't handle the nesting.  It's not as easy to work with but sometimes your only choice.

Answer (score 10):

***EDIT: the [sparsify gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sparsify) was released as a general solution to this problem.***

---

Here's an implementation I worked up a couple months ago. You'll need to parse the JSON into a hash, then use Sparsify to sparse the hash.

```
# Extend into a hash to provide sparse and unsparse methods. 
# 
# {'foo'=>{'bar'=>'bingo'}}.sparse #=> {'foo.bar'=>'bingo'}
# {'foo.bar'=>'bingo'}.unsparse => {'foo'=>{'bar'=>'bingo'}}
# 
module Sparsify
  def sparse(options={})
    self.map do |k,v|
      prefix = (options.fetch(:prefix,[])+[k])
      next Sparsify::sparse( v, options.merge(:prefix => prefix ) ) if v.is_a? Hash
      { prefix.join(options.fetch( :separator, '.') ) => v}
    end.reduce(:merge) || Hash.new
  end
  def sparse!
    self.replace(sparse)
  end

  def unsparse(options={})
    ret = Hash.new
    sparse.each do |k,v|
      current = ret
      key = k.to_s.split( options.fetch( :separator, '.') )
      current = (current[key.shift] ||= Hash.new) until (key.size<=1)
      current[key.first] = v
    end
    return ret
  end
  def unsparse!(options={})
    self.replace(unsparse)
  end

  def self.sparse(hsh,options={})
    hsh.dup.extend(self).sparse(options)
  end

  def self.unsparse(hsh,options={})
    hsh.dup.extend(self).unsparse(options)
  end

  def self.extended(base)
    raise ArgumentError, "<#{base.inspect}> must be a Hash" unless base.is_a? Hash
  end
end
```

usage:

```
external_data = JSON.decode( external_json )
flattened = Sparsify.sparse( external_data, :separator => '-' )
```

This was originally created because we were working with storing a set of things in Mongo, which allowed us to use sparse keys (dot-separated) on updates to update some contents of a nested hash without overwriting unrelated keys.

Comment: If there is interest, I will gladly gemify and maintain, along with tests.

Answer (score 4):

One more option:

```
class Hash
  def smash(prefix = nil)
    inject({}) do |acc, (k, v)|
      key = prefix.to_s + k
      if Hash === v
        acc.merge(v.smash(key + '-'))
      else
        acc.merge(key => v)
      end
    end
  end
end

hash = {
  'f' => 100,
  'z' => {'j' => 25},
  'a' => {'b' => {'c' => 1}}
}

puts hash.smash # => {"f"=>100, "z-j"=>25, "a-b-c"=>1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to tackle this is not to flatten the hash, but to access it as though it were flattened.  For example, given this hash:

```
h = {
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => {
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 3,
  },
}
```

then this function:

```
NESTED_KEY_SEPARATOR = '-'
NESTED_KEY_REGEX = /^(.*?)(?:#{NESTED_KEY_SEPARATOR}(.*))?$/

def nested_fetch(key, hash)
  return hash if key.empty?
  first_part_of_key, rest_of_key = NESTED_KEY_REGEX.match(key).captures
  value = hash[first_part_of_key]
  if value.is_a?(Hash)
    nested_hash_fetch(value, rest_of_key || '')
  elsif rest_of_key
    nil
  else
    value
  end
end
```

Will let you retrieve nested hash elements by concatenating the individual hash keys together with KEY_SEPARATOR (set to dash here, but could be any character that never appears as a key in the hash you need to search):

```
p nested_fetch('a', h)      # => 1
p nested_fetch('b-c', h)    # => 2
```

If you give a partially qualified key, you get the hash that matched at that point:

```
p nested_fetch('b', h)      # => {"c"=>2, "d"=>3}
```

And if you give a key that doesn't exist, you get nil:

```
p nested_fetch('b-x', h)    # => nil
```

This could be monkey-patched onto Hash, if desired, by simply enclosing the above code in class Hash, and by giving self as the default to argument hash:

```
class Hash
  NESTED_KEY_SEPARATOR = '-'
  NESTED_KEY_REGEX = /^(.*?)(?:#{KEY_SEPARATOR}(.*))?$/

  def nested_fetch(key, hash = self)
  ...
end
```