# how can I programmatically identify which keys have sub key-value-pairs in a JSON doc?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I fetch a JSON document and need to programmatically "flatten" the keys for another third-party service.

What this means is, if my JSON doc comes back with the following:

```
{'first_name' => "Joe", 'hoffman' => {'patterns' => ['negativity', 'self-sabotage'], 'right_road' => 'happy family'}, 'mbti' => 'INTJ'}
```

I need to be able to know to create a "flat" key-value pair for a third-party service like this:

```
first_name = "Joe"
hoffman.patterns = "negativity, self-sabotage"
hoffman.right_road = "happy family"
mbti = "INTJ"
```

Once I know there's a sub-document, the parsing I think I have figured out just appending the sub-keys with `key + '.' + "{subkey}"` but right now, don't know which ones are straight key-value and which one's have sub-documents.

Question:

a) How can I parse the JSON to know which keys have sub-documents (additional key-values)?

b) Suggestions on ways to create a string from an array

Comment: Isn't this just a case of checking whether the value for a given key is a Hash?

Comment: How nested is the document?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521230/flattening-nested-hash-to-a-single-hash-with-ruby-rails , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064648/ruby-converting-a-nested-ruby-hash-to-an-un-nested-one , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712679/flatten-a-nested-json-object , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also monkey patch `Hash` to do this on it's own like so:

```
class Hash
  def flatten_keys(prefix=nil)
    each_pair.map do |k,v|
      key = [prefix,k].compact.join(".")
      v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.flatten_keys(key) : [key,v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(", ") : v]
    end.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
  end
  def to_flat_hash
    Hash[flatten_keys]
  end
end
```

Then it would be

```
require 'json'
h = JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE)
#=> {'first_name' => "Joe", 'hoffman' => {'patterns' => ['negativity', 'self-sabotage'], 'right_road' => 'happy family'}, 'mbti' => 'INTJ'}
h.to_flat_hash
#=> {"first_name"=>"Joe", "hoffman.patterns"=>"negativity, self-sabotage", "hoffman.right_road"=>"happy family", "mbti"=>"INTJ"}
```

Will work with additional nesting too

```
h =  {"first_name"=>"Joe", "hoffman"=>{"patterns"=>["negativity", "self-sabotage"], "right_road"=>"happy family", "wrong_road"=>{"bad_choices"=>["alcohol", "heroin"]}}, "mbti"=>"INTJ"}
h.to_flat_hash
#=> {"first_name"=>"Joe", "hoffman.patterns"=>"negativity, self-sabotage", "hoffman.right_road"=>"happy family", "hoffman.wrong_road.bad_choices"=>"alcohol, heroin", "mbti"=>"INTJ"}
```

Comment: Nice Answer And example

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty recursive proc:

```
# assuming you've already `JSON.parse` the incoming json into this hash:
a = {'first_name' => "Joe", 'hoffman' => {'patterns' => ['negativity', 'self-sabotage'], 'right_road' => 'happy family'}, 'mbti' => 'INTJ'}

# define a recursive proc:
flatten_keys = -> (h, prefix = "") do
  @flattened_keys ||= {}
  h.each do |key, value|
    # Here we check if there's "sub documents" by asking if the value is a Hash
    # we also pass in the name of the current prefix and key and append a . to it
    if value.is_a? Hash
      flatten_keys.call value, "#{prefix}#{key}."
    else
      # if not we concatenate the key and the prefix and add it to the @flattened_keys hash 
      @flattened_keys["#{prefix}#{key}"] = value
    end
  end
  @flattened_keys
end

flattened = flatten_keys.call a
# => "first_name"=>"Joe", "hoffman.patterns"=>["negativity", "self-sabotage"], "hoffman.right_road"=>"happy family", "mbti"=>"INTJ"}
```

And then, to turn the arrays into strings just `join` them:

```
flattened.inject({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
  value = value.join(', ') if value.is_a? Array
  hash.merge! key => value
end

# => {"first_name"=>"Joe", "hoffman.patterns"=>"negativity, self-sabotage", "hoffman.right_road"=>"happy family", "mbti"=>"INTJ"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647997/converting-a-nested-hash-into-a-flat-hash#answer-23861946):

```ruby
def flat_hash(h,f=[],g={})
  return g.update({ f=>h }) unless h.is_a? Hash
  h.each { |k,r| flat_hash(r,f+[k],g) }
  g
end

h = { :a => { :b => { :c => 1,
                      :d => 2 },
              :e => 3 },
      :f => 4 }

result = {}
flat_hash(h) #=> {[:a, :b, :c]=>1, [:a, :b, :d]=>2, [:a, :e]=>3, [:f]=>4}
  .each{ |k, v| result[k.join('.')] = v } #=> {"a.b.c"=>1, "a.b.d"=>2, "a.e"=>3, "f"=>4}
```